# Use of collection view tool in Cooja

Tags: contiki

I'm trying to figure out how to use "collection view" tool to capture characteristics of wireless sensor network.
I tried the example "collect-tree-sparse-lossy.csc" in folder examples/ipv6/rpl-collect. I can see it runs with output messages.
However, there is nothing in the collection view even when I try clicking any button. See the following picture for more details:

[image]

[image]

When I click on button "Program Nodes..", an error message shown:

[image]

How can I turn on collection view tool?

Comment: did you solve this problem. i have this problem? how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

When running Cooja, you should have already loaded the correct firmware. Therefore there is no need to program them. You need to press "Start Collect", though.

Comment: Ok, I can use Collection View now. It needs enough time to collect data before showing on Collection View.
However, only sky mote works. I couldn't emulate z1 mote. Can you do that?

Comment: No I haven't worked with z1 motes, yet. As they are msp-based they _should_ work. The Gui is just a convenient interface to send commands via the serial. Did you test sending them manually using the virtual serial? Or in other words: Are you sure the software running on the nodes works?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that the software running on the nodes works because I can see log messages and radio traffic between nodes.